# Is ubuntu adopting performance for gaming?

Tags: games

I was just wondering if the future builds of ubuntu would give better performance with games and multi-tasking.
Many threads suggest that ubuntu gives slower performance with many active applications than Windows. I agree that linux platform is yet to rival with windows when it comes to multi-tasking.
But still, can the future builds (hopefully the next one) of ubuntu give good performance with games and stuff like high end graphics?

Comment: Can you give examples of these threads? Because from what STEAM says, linux, especially ubuntu, gives better fps than windows in the same configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  **`STEAM`** is on linux and probabbly for ubuntu than you can play almost any kind of heavy graphical games and anything and form than forward you will see drastic changes on gaming on `LINUX/UBUNTU. And its not that ubuntu is slow unity has to be improved a bit but if you play games on Steam than there should be no problem.

And yes now vendors of PC's are taking ubuntu seriously like DELL, ACER and now they will make hardware more compatible with LINUX and there own drivers for Graphic cards ETC and than you will see the real power of linux and you should know that Android is Linux and you know there are alot of heavy games for android if android can run heavy games on small mobile device than why not ubuntu on multi-core device.

Comment: steam has been on linux for quite some time. I believe it's in ubuntu's repositories even...

Comment: yea but frpm linux above i meant to say ubuntu